# Beginner query: Using function parameters with a for loop, skipping the loop for some reason

Tags: javascript

I imagine this is something pretty simple but I'm stumped and think this could be a good learning moment for me.

Here's the code:

```
var sumAll = function(lowRange, highRange) {
  var sumOf;
  var i;

  for (i = lowRange; i > highRange; i++) {
    sumOf += i;
  }

  return sumOf;
}

module.exports = sumAll
```

I'm working my way through the odin project, currently doing TDD section. So the function skeleton and final line of code was premade. The function parameters in this case are 1, 4. Expected result of 10.

Instead my test is throwing back `undefined`. I checked and this changes depending on what I define it as at the top.

It is as if it's skipping the loop all together, I've no idea why this would be.

Comment: Your loop test condition checks for `i > highRange`. If `lowRange` is 1 and `highRange` is 4, is that true at the very first check of that condition?

Comment: Your loop will not run, and therefore `sumOf` that is initialized to `undefined` will be returned. You can set `sumOf = 0` and flip your loop condition to `i < highRange`.

Comment: Looks like you’re trying to calculate a geometric sum. You don’t need a for loop for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop's 3 major pieces can typically be understood like this.

- Initialize the variable
- Continue looping for as long as the condition is true
- Change the variable's value after every iteration

During step two of the list above, your code is running `i > highrange`. This will immediately test false and skip your loop, because `i` has a value of `lowrange`, and I assume `lowrange > highrange` will never be true.  What you want in its place is `i <= highrange`, "less than or equal to."

For loops are tricky, these little mistakes will follow you even into advanced territories. :o

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help, I was thinking of the second piece as "exit condition" so had falsely assumed the loop would exit once the condition was met. It's more like an "active condition" or something. Thanks so much for this comment, it really broke the whole error down for me :)

Comment: @Christopher Magennis I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop never executes because you set `i` equal to `lowRange` and the execute condition is `i > highRange`. I assume `lowRange < highRange` so it terminates without entering the loop, since it will run while `i` is greater than `highRange`, but it never is.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your accumulator

```
var sumOf = 0;
```

and change your loop condition

```
for (i = lowRange; i <= highRange; i++) {
```